# Objective c: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instance, unrecognized-selector

I know this kind of question is repeatedly floating around over and over, but i haven't been able to solve my problem with any answer i found :( .

I'm developing an application and i need to fetch audio stream. I decided to go with MPMoviePlayer, so i did this:

```
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"    
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    ...     
    IBOutlet MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie;
    ...
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie;
```

and in the implementation, i've just @synthesize-d it.

And now, whenever I allocate it and try to access it's members or methods, I get this damn error **unrecognized selector sent to instance** on the first line after the initialization:

```
self.theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://netvarp.kringvarp.fo:554/radio/16/playlist.m3u8"]];
self.theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;       
    ...
```

(this is in viewDidLoad method).

I get the error in this line:

```
self.theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

or whatever i call after the initialization.

Same goes if I remove the IBOutlet, if i call it without 'self', if declare a **MPMoviePlayerController**. I can't figure out what i'm I doing wrong for 2 days! So embarrassing :(

Any help will be appreciated.

I forgot to mention, Target OS is > 3.0. Everything works okay on the simulator, but not on devices (iPhone 2G and iPhone 3G, both with IOS 3.1.3)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd guess the URL is broken, or the content does not work with MPMoviePlayer.  Moreover, I tried to open it manually using iTunes and VLC, but nothing happened, either.

Comment: Why are you using an outlet to a movie player view controller?

Comment: Which selector is being called and not recognized? Is it -theMovie, -moviePlayer or -setControlStyle? Could you maybe provide some more code? Are those lines of code actually called in a method in FirstViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Apple Documentations says:
controlStyle is only available in iOS 3.2 and later.

I think this could be your problem, since this method is not available on your 3.1.3 device, but It is on the simulator, I guess (4.2.1).

Comment: You're right. I've been calling methods that are not implemented in version 3.1.3. I've cleared all of those methods and it all works fine. 

Thank you, and thanks to WrightsCS for the help below also ;)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to post the crash output. `unrecognized selector` means you are trying to call something that doesn't exist, for example:

```
[self doSomethingSpecial];
```

if `doSomethingSpecial` doesn't exist in your controller, you will receive the **unrecognized selector sent to instance**